# Questions involve Integrals and Sequence

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^ \infty$ be a non-negative sequence, let $k ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and let $f : [k, ∞) → \mathbb{R}$
be a function that is integrable on $[k, b]$ for every $b > k$.
Prove or disprove each of the following statements:

1. If $\int_k^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges.
2. If $\lim_{n \to \infty}(n \cdot a_n)=0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.
3. If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-a_n}$ is convergent, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n^7}$ is convergent.

---

So for 1, I think that it is incorrect, but I can't find a function to counter the statement.

For 2, define $a_n=\frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$, obvious $\lim_{n \to \infty}(n \cdot a_n)=0$, and we know that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}=\infty$, but we do need the sum from $n=1$ which is undefined in this case. Can I say that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}=\infty$ because its tail diverges?

For 3, my first guess was to define $a_n=\sqrt[7]n$ for every $n \ge 1$, and use the ratio test, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion will be amazing!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's indeed false. Just take $f(x)=|\sin(\pi x)|$.
2. You are right.
3. That has [already been asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4148049/446262).

Comment: Thank you for that! I was trying to prove 3 with the ratio test and got a limit of 1, do you recommend solving it in other way? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot possibly prove a false statement.

Comment: Let me correct my comment: I tried to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt[7]n}}$ converges (so the statement will be false)

Comment: Should I use the comparasion test:  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt[7]n}} \le  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{n}}<\infty$ ?

Comment: No. That doesn't work since we actually have $e^{-\sqrt[7]n}\geqslant e^{-n}$. I used the integral test.

Comment: Yes you are right. what about $\sqrt[n]n$ for every $n \ge 7$ ? $e^{- \sqrt[n]n} \ge e^{- \sqrt[7]n}$ for every $n \ge 7$

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the fact that$$n\geqslant 7\implies e^{-\sqrt[7]n}\leqslant e^{-\sqrt[n]n}?$$

Comment: Yes, do you think that will work with the $\sqrt[n] .$ test?

Comment: No, because the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\sqrt[n]n}$ actually diverges, since we don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\sqrt[n]n}=0$.

Comment: Yes alright, I will try the integral test. Thanks again!

Comment: I will appreciate a hint to solve this integral if you can :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124632/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-calculuslover).